# Language 0 does not exist on site … after replacing it | TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a new TYPO3 System.

In the Site Configuration I have deleted the default language (English) and created a new one (German).

When I want to display my website in the Page Module there is the following error:

> Language 0 does not exist on site autogenerated-1-…

[image: Occuring Error]

Where can I configure the language that is being selected or is it possible to change the language id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have a site configuration with a language that uses uid=0. I assume you're using TYPO3 v12?
If yes, I'd suggest the following:

- go to site configuration
- delete all languages
- In the list "Available Languages for this Site" there should be then at least one entry which is called "English [0]". Select that one to create a new language
- Edit that entry and change all values to German.

Comment: No, i am using TYPO3 v11. But your solution worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your Site configuration is a YAML file stored in your docroot `config/sites/<identifier>/config.yaml` (Composer based installation) or `typo3conf/sites/<identifier>/config.yaml` (legacy installation).

You can write configuration directly as text

```
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    websiteTitle: 'My websitetitle'
    navigationTitle: 'deutsch'
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
    languageId: 0
```

and adjust websitetitle. Keep indention.